# For each in double list

Tags: vb.net, list, for-loop, razor

Is it possible to do a for each joining two list and browse through the new "duo list" ?
something like :

```
For Each elm In list1 Join list2
     elm.obj1 // objet with list1 type
     elm.obj2 // object with list2 type
next elm
```

Lists have the same length.

Comment: What means the have same length and only one object? So both contain only one object? Is it possible that they will ever contain more? How do you want to join them at all?? Via index or via some other logic like a common Id? How is it related to VB6?

Comment: I mean by one object there isn't a obj1.something possible, so no common idea obviously. Via index is good I just want to know what are the possibilies

Answer (score 4):

You can join by index with LINQ's `Enumerable.Zip` and create an anonymous type:

```
Dim zipped = list1.Zip(list2, Function(obj1, obj2) New With {Key obj1, Key obj2})

For Each pair In zipped
    Console.WriteLine(pair.obj1)
    Console.WriteLine(pair.obj2)
Next
```

Note that `zipped` is not a collection yet but a query. Whenever you will enumerate it(f.e. with  `For Each`, `First`, `ToList` etc.) you will execute this query again. If you need to persist it you can create a list or array(`ToList`/`ToArray`) and access this instead.
The lazy evaluation of many LINQ methods is called [Deferred Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt692927.aspx).

Comment: Sweet.  Was aware of `Zip` but never used it.  I'll modify my `Tuple` example below to use it instead.

Comment: You could/should add `Key` in the definition of the anonymous type to make the fields read-only : `New With {Key obj, Key obj2}`

Comment: I've always wondered what to use the `Zip()` extension for, and now I finally know! Very nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to enumerate a single, combined list then you would do this:

```
For Each item In list1.Concat(list2)
    'Use item here.
Next
```

If what you actually mean is that you want to access the items in both lists at the same index at the same time then how would a `For Each` loop make sense?  In that case you'd use a `For` loop and get both items by index:

```
For i = 0 To list1.Count - 1
    Dim item1 = list1(i)
    Dim item2 = list2(i)

    'Use item1 and item2 here.
Next
```

Taking into account the `Zip` method used in the other answer and combining it with my `Tuple` suggestion:

```
For Each tpl In list1.Zip(list2, Function(a, b) AddressOf Tuple.Create)
    Console.WriteLine(tpl.Item1)
    Console.WriteLine(tpl.Item2)
Next
```

Comment: you can use `AddressOf` with a method group instead of using a lambda : `Zip(list2, AddressOf Tuple.Create)`

Comment: @Sehnsucht, indeed. Updated.